# Cannot get azure blob image after adding "http://shhh.blob.core.windows.net/*" to cordova whitelist

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, visual-studio-cordova

Hi I'm trying to add domain access to my cordova app, however after adding this
"http://shhh.blob.core.windows.net/*" 
to Visual Studio Corodva Domain access list, I can no longer get the image (got 404 error).

Other domain access URL seems to work just fine, but just this one doesn't.

The URL of the image is 
http://shhh.blob.core.windows.net:80/secretimages/2767E586-E310-4C8A-A228-05EE0B69C0CE.jpeg

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks so much!